# Compare list of string with list of webelements

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For sure it's trivial case but I'm having list of webelements and array of strings. I need to check if list of webelements contains string inside that array.

```
public IList<IWebElement> PaymentNames => driver.WaitForElementsVisible(By.XPath(paymentNameLocator));
string[] expectedPaymentNames = {"Cash","Card"};

    public bool ArePaymentNamesCorrectlyShown(string[] paymentNames)
    {
       return  PaymentNames.Any(t => t.Text == ????);
    }
```

I was trying to do it by linqu but no idea how to compare it with array...

Comment: What string do you need from web element? Something like WebElement.getText() (that can be your solution) or you need some other string?

Comment: Actually from web element list I have strings to get (probably one by one) by .Text method on specific webelement. Then I need to compare if such string (from webelement list) is visible (equals) the string from the array list. For example in my test im using three types of payments (A,B,C) I'm defying list of those. Then I would like to assert if that list matches with list of the web elements.

Comment: Then just create Array of strings and when your element is visible add "WebElement.Text" e.g. arrayStrings[0] = driver.FindElement(By.Id("whatever")).Text; and after you can do any assertion.

Comment: Provide a sample code and data and tell us what you result need

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. You cannot compare `t.Text` to one thing. You need to see if the text is contained in the expected payment names:

```
return PaymentNames.Any(t => paymentNames.Contains(t.Text));
```

This particular `Contains(...)` method is in the System.Linq namespace, which you should already be using in this C# file.